# Gradle: Add Github Repository to librarys

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

so I'm trying to code a forge mod for minecraft which uses gradle. And I'm a complete noob when it comes to gradle because I've never used it before. So I'm trying to acces a github repository that I need for the mod, when I run the client as configuration it works perfectly fine, but when i build the project and try to launch minecraft with it, it says that it cant find the classes from the github repo.

I am using `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` as repository and `compile ('com.github.HypixelDev.PublicAPI:Java:2.0.0')` as dependency. Again when it comes to gradle I have no Idea on how to use it, so please forgive me if I gave you unclear details.

I would really appreciate any help on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to use a dependency from github? i'm not really sure what you are trying to do but if you are trying to use a dependency from github then i would try just downloading the code from github and adding it to the mod .

Comment: I'll try doing that